How to get rid of the line in Blender
I connected two parts of the mask in one, I joined them, and remeshed them.
But I have this line, how to get rid of it?
I need it to be as smooth as the mask itself.


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this.
